# Port forwarding cyclic rules

Tags: windows, proxy, port-forwarding, netsh

I am trying to use netsh command to port forward some ports so that I can redirect traffic from devices on my LAN to applications running locally.

I have setup port forwarding via netsh

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=7777 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=7777 connectaddress=127.0.0.1`

However, when I try to connect to a tcp server running on my machine from my remote device on the LAN, wireshark shows a ton of SYN requests. I assume it is because since I am listening on all interfaces, the forwarded traffic to 127.0.0.1 retriggers the rule, hence causing a ton of recursive calls.

From my understanding, one rule should only be triggered once per request. Is this correct? If yes, how can I fix the above problem. I'm assuming there are some flags I need to set.